# How can I review already merged code in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I'm working with a large and old code base, and we switched to using GitLab recently.  We have locked our main branches and require all changes to be reviewed before merge which is working well.

We have lots of old code that was never reviewed, and we want to start a process of systematically going through and reviewing it now.  Is there a way to do this in GitLab that means we can annotate the code with comments like with a merge request, even though the code will not be in a separate branch?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to review code outside of a Merge/Pull Request in Gitlab.

Code reviews are typically done through merge/pull requests, so if you want to review the entire code base then you will have to use third party extensions/plugins in IDEs which will let you annotate code, and such extensions usually store the comments as text files.

For example, in VS code one such extension is.

https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/vscode-code-review

This extension exports the review comments as a csv file. This csv file can be imported in Gitlab issue, which will create one issue per review comment.